# Async Multithreading likes Android OS's Multi touch

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

i hope to do something like this

=> mouse Left click 2 points at same time but i can use my mouse

or

=> mouse Left Down 2 points at same time but i can use my original mouse

(example: two points still pressing but i can use my computer mouse (move, click, wheeling)

likes android OS's Multi Touch)

and after 1 sec, mouse Left Up 2 points at same time too

is it possible to make it in visual C ++ 2015?

Comment: You can't click 2 points at the same time using only one mouse; there's something not quite clear in your question, can you rephrase it?

Comment: okay then can i push down two points?

Comment: Well, you need a multitouch-capable device and a multitouch-enabled driver, from what I know. Even two mice will be driving the same pointer on the screen, not two. And it also depends what platform you're developing for: is it Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android?

Comment: it's Windows! hmm.. can i pressing down keyboard and mouse at same time without stopping console?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve nor why but Windows has support for multi-touch applications, as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh406720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. Hope you'll find useful details there.